# Поразрядное вычитание, язык C

Tags: c

Можно пример поразрядного вычитания в коде? Не очень понимаю, о чем речь.

Comment: Может вычитание без заема из предыдущего разряда, ну так это логическая XOR, обозначаемая `^`

Comment: @Mike я так понял надо,стобиком

Comment: @Артем поразрядное вычитание чисел(грубо говоря как в школе,в столбик)для длинных чисел,понятно?

Comment: @Артем , по-моему, для больших чисел нужны свои классы со своей арифметикой. Не понятна осталась область применения.

Comment: Поразрядное - двоичное или десятичное?

Comment: @maestro десятичное

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned char x = 0b00000100, y = 0b00000010;
   unsigned char res, carry = 0;
   unsigned char n;
   unsigned char xx, yy;
   for (n = 0; n < 8; ++n) {
      xx = x & 1 ? 0xFF: 0;
      yy = y & 1 ? 0xFF: 0;
      res = carry ? (~(xx^yy)) : xx^yy;
      carry = carry ? ((~xx)|yy) : ((~xx)&yy);
      printf( res ? "1" : "0" );
      x >>= 1;
      y >>= 1;
   }
   printf("\r\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: я боюсь даже спросить,  это а-b?

Comment: Это x - y........

Comment: просто выглядит мягко говоря страшно. Я просто не верю что это оптимально...

Comment: Язык С просто не слишком приспособлен для работы с разрядами. Вот и приходится имитировать Verilog.